# How to Join Only category if subcategory is null?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

How do I join Category if Subcategory is Null. The below query builder is working for Category that have Subcategory too, but not working for those category where Subcategory is Null.

```
public function Index(){
    $post = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', 'categories.id')
    ->join('subcategories', 'posts.subcategory_id', 'subcategories.id')
    ->select('posts.*', 'categories.category_en', 'subcategories.subcategory_eng')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('backend.post.index', compact('post'));
}
```

Comment: Maybe `leftJoin` to the `subcategories`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `leftJooin` to `subcategories`.  See more about [Left Join](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause) in Laravel.
As you didn't shared table schema of above tables to understand the relationship between them. If `subcategories` table have column `category_id` which relate subcategory to it parent than follow the below code:

```
->leftJoin('subcategories', 'categories.id', 'subcategories.category_id')
```

Replace above written line of code in your function like I did below:

```
public function Index(){
    $post = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', 'categories.id')
    ->leftJoin('subcategories', 'categories.id', 'subcategories.category_id')
    ->select('posts.*', 'categories.category_en', 'subcategories.subcategory_eng')
    ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('backend.post.index', compact('post'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add whereNull condition for parent id is null.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `leftjoin` in your query:

```
public function Index(){
    $post = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('categories', 'posts.category_id', 'categories.id')
    ->leftJoin('subcategories', 'posts.subcategory_id', 'subcategories.id')
    ->select('posts.*', 'categories.category_en', 'subcategories.subcategory_eng')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    return view('backend.post.index', compact('post'));
}
```